# Matching strings between whitespaces without including them

Tags: c#, .net, regex

I'm trying to match strings between whitespaces, but not have the whitespaces included in the results. For example:

`Hi, my name is Tudor.` should match `my`, `name` and `is`. My regex is:

```
(?<=\s){token}(?=\s)
```

I'm also curious why using

```
(?:\s){token}(?:\s)
```

Still keeps the whitespaces in the matches.

So far regex 1 seems to work fine, but I'm wondering if it's correct for all cases since I'm not a regex expert by any means.

Comment: Because the latter consumes spaces like token itself and the former leaves them alone though asserting them. BTW your working regex is what you want.

Comment: Do you also want to match the first word in a line when it is followed by a whitespace? I just mean to say...are you referring only to spaces or whitespaces which include newlines too? [`(?<=\s)\w+(?=\s)`](https://regex101.com/r/q6OToH/1) vs [`(?<= )\w+(?= )`](https://regex101.com/r/q6OToH/2)